# What are $Extend\$Deleted file system entries and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, disk-volume

I'd like to shrink an NTFS data partition on one of my servers. Unfortunately, it has an "unmovable file" located at an inconvenient position.

Here is the relevant event log entry:

> A volume shrink analysis was initiated on volume Daten (C:\Daten). This event log entry details information about the last unmovable file that could limit the maximum number of reclaimable bytes.
>
> Diagnostic details:
>    - The last unmovable file appears to be:
>    \$Extend\$Deleted:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION
>    - The last cluster of the file is: 0x1138f943
>    - Shrink potential target (LCN address): 0x18a51d6
>    - The NTFS file flags are: ----I
>    - Shrink phase: <analysis>
>
> To find more details about this file please use the "fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{4ad80633-d2d5-415e-97b4-9ad5f648bb0c} 0x1138f943" command.

The command mentioned at the bottom of the event log entry does not yield any useful additional information:

```
C:\> fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{4ad80633-d2d5-415e-97b4-9ad5f648bb0c} 0x1138f943
Cluster 0x000000001138f943 used by ----I \$Extend\$Deleted:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION
```

(Note (note sure if it's relevant): The last thing I did on the drive was to delete all shadow copies.)

I am aware that `$Extend` is not a "regular" folder but some kind of NTFS system file. Thus, my question:

**What is this $Extend\$Deleted file system entry and how do I get rid of it?** (Or, at least, get rid of its "unmovability" so that I can shrink my volume...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the `$Extend\$Deleted` folder as well and have been combing the web for information. I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer, but here is what I found:

- While `$Extend` has been around for a long time, [`$Deleted` appears to be a relatively new addition, appearing in Windows 10 for client OS'es,](https://exatrack.com/public/vuln_NTFS_EN.pdf) unsure about server.
- [Files appear in `$Deleted` when they have an open handle but a request has been made to delete them](https://dfir.ru/2020/03/21/the-extenddeleted-directory/).
- It appears that this can be related to an [issue with an older version of Cygwin](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/storage-leak-on-ntfs-system-drive-in-windows-10/df049b94-1414-4ed3-8b8f-f4eecfc8c9f5) whereby Cygwin causes files to appear in `$Deleted` but never get actually removed.
- At least one individual was able to remove the `$Deleted` files by booting to Windows, normally it seems these files should be cleared out upon reboot (since all handles will be released).
- But it probably isn't restricted only to Cygwin, [it appears this implementation is part of Windows POSIX support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112795/os-mkdir-can-fail-with-permissionerror-after-successful-shutil-rmtree-on-windows).

Comment: I got this problem when deleting a big file from Windows Explorer while a Cygwin process was reading from it. It disappeared after a few minutes, didn't need to reboot. Free space in the partition was getting close to 0% so maybe Windows deleted it because of that